# Call platform specific code from core project

Tags: libgdx, admob

I just Implemented ads for Android in my game using [this guide](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Google-Mobile-Ads-in-Libgdx-%28replaces-deprecated-AdMob%29). 
It works fine, I have an interface in my core project that the Android Activity implements.

However my problem is that you need to send this implemented interface to the core project, and then pass it as a parameter to your first Screen, where you can use it, ex:

```
public MyGdxGame(PlatformSpecific ps) //Android class that handle fb-login and ads
{
    this.ps = ps;
}

@Override
public void create ()
{
   setScreen(new LoginScreen(this, ps);
}
```

This was fine for when I needed fb-login since I'm using that in the `LoginScreen`, but I want to be able to create my ads in other Screens (after a game is finished) by calling `createAd`-method in interface.

Do I have to keep passing `ps` between all the Screens just so I can use it in a Screen that only gets used quite rarely, or is there some way to get to this interface from my Screen without passing it to the constructor? Kind of like when you initiate an object, ex:

```
private PlatformSpecific ps = new PlatformSpecific();
```

Or does LibGdx have some library to support this scenario maybe? Worst case I could just pass `ps` between all constructors but feels like a pretty ugly solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
Store PlatformSpecific in a global static variable. That allows you to access anywhere in your code without passing it in every constructor.

Soluatio 2:
Have MyPlatformContext class which provides access to PlatformSpecific. Then pass this MyPlatformContext object to your screen constructors. If you extend your platform specific code later you do not have to change the screen constructors. Just edit MyPlatformContextMyPlatformContext class.

Pseudo code:

```
class MyPlatformContext {
    private FacbookPlatform fb;
    private AdmobPlatform admob

    FacbookPlatform getFacebook() {
        return fb;
    }
    ...
}
```